# Max min notation

Tags: notation

Imagine, I have a symmetric matrix $B$. I want a set of rows for which I can get the maximum from the least value of all rows. For example if $B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}- & 3& 4\\3& -& 6\\ 4 &6& -\end{smallmatrix}\right)$,
then $3$  is the least value for row $1$, $3$ for row $2$, and $4$ for row $3$. Among these only row $1$ and row $2$ have the maximum value (i.e. $3$). So, I want to express this mathematically. So far I got this:

$\underset{i\in\{1,\dots,S\}}{\operatorname{argmax}}\bigl(\min\limits_{\substack{i\neq  j\,\\j\in\{1,\dots,S\}}} ({B_{ij}})\bigr)$

Comment: 1. The example of $B$ is not symmetric.  2. Why exclude the diagonal $i=j$?

Comment: my bad, fixed the example; excluding the diagonal is a requirement.

Comment: The notation $\{1,S\}$ is unusual for $1$ through $S$.  Sometimes $[S]$ would be used or $\{1,\dots,S\}$.  Other than that, it looks OK.

Comment: I would suggest replacing repetitive sentence "$3$ is the least value for row $1$ ..." by a table.
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{row index }i & \text{least value} \\\hline
1 & 3 \\
2 & 3 \\
3 & 4
\end{array}
This enables us to read your question faster.

Comment: @MichaelBurr dont you think $B_{ij}$ denotes an element rather than a set, my confusion lies there. It seems to me I am trying to find min from an element rather than a set.

Comment: Minimum of an element doesn't make sense. You always take the minimum of a set. What is the minimum of 1?

Comment: Exactly my point, @Raskolnikov . So how should I change the notation?

Comment: What's wrong with Michael Burr's comment? It is on point.

Comment: @Raskolnikov , I meant doesn't $B_{ij}$ means only one element? I am having hard time to express it as a set.  Btw I have corrected the notation for 1 through S ({1,...,S}). Kindly take a look.

Comment: OK, I understand your confusion now. I'd rather look at $B_{ij}$ like a function value. Hence, when you vary $i$ and $j$, the range of values for $B_{ij}$ varies too. So you're really looking at the $\max\{B_{ij}|j\neq i \; , \; j\in\{1,\ldots,S\}\}$. But it is pretty standard to notate this more succinctly as $\max_{j\neq i \; , \; j\in\{1,\ldots,S\}} B_{ij}$ or even just $\max_{j\neq i} B_{ij}$ as long as it is understood from the previous definitions of $B$ and $j$ that $j \in \{1,\ldots,S\}$.